# Rounding the numeric output of pandas pivot tables and SciPy's stats.mode

Tags: pandas, scipy, rounding, statsmodels

Rather than the mean score displaying as 91.144105, how to display instead 91.1?
Rather than the mode score displaying as ([90.0], [77]), how to display instead 90?

code snippet and output:

[image]

```py
from scipy import stats, import numpy as np

pd.pivot_table(df_inspections_violations, index= ['ACTIVITY YEAR', 'FACILITY ZIP'], values= "SCORE", 
               aggfunc= ['mean', 'median', stats.mode])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `style.format` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values)).

But you'd better split the `mode SCORE` column in `value` and (I guess) `index`, so that you can use a dictionary to control each single column, for example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.linspace(0, 1, 7),
    'b': np.linspace(31, 90, 7),
    'c': np.arange(10, 17)
})

df.style.format({
    'a': "{:.2f}",
    'b': "{:.1f}",
    'c': int,
})
```

Output

```
    a       b       c
0   0.00    31.0    10
1   0.17    40.8    11
2   0.33    50.7    12
3   0.50    60.5    13
4   0.67    70.3    14
5   0.83    80.2    15
6   1.00    90.0    16
```